# What's the difference between HTML Tags and HTML Objects?

Tags: javascript, html

I was referring some HTML tags and i got confused with the terms "HTML Tags" and "HTML Objects" when i came across different sites. Some of the HTML Tags are available in both the HTML Tag Reference and HTML Element Objects Reference, like "canvas", "li, "ol" and so on... in the following sites.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp
and in "HTML Element Objects Reference" part of the page
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp.
So, how do they differ? What's the functions of them?. 
How do i exactly refer them?
"HTML Tags" or "HTML Objects"?

Comment: Always try making a parallel research with other sources when finding something in w3schools. http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools is unreliable, confused, and confusing, and attempts to understand its inaccurate language are futile; any answer to a question about the meaning of some terms they use would also be primarily opinion based – a subjective interpretation of sloppy wordings. They probably mean HTML *elements* by “HTML Tags” and HTML elements as DOM objects by “HTML Objects”.

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags are what make up the markup of an HTML document.

For example `<p> <a> <body> <script>` are tags.

Javascript can be used to make web pages dynamic. With browser based javascript there is the [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). This turns the HTML document into a collection of objects that can be manipulated by javascript. These are the HTML objects w3schools are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to two different things. The first link is about the actual tags you see in an HTML document. The second link is about the JavaScript dom api. When they say object, they are talking about the JavaScript object representation of the tag. Take a look at this link http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_li.asp. This shows that the dom api is creating an li tag for the HTML document. Below are a few more sites you can check out as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard the term "HTML object". For the difference between tags and elements have a look at http://perfectionkills.com/tag-is-not-an-element-or-is-it/ and http://annevankesteren.nl/2004/05/tags-vs-elements - tldr: a tag is the piece of markup whereas an element is the semantic part of a document.

Any talk about object probably refers to entities in the [Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which represents the API that you use to access elements programmatically.